# Class whose instances are treated as Any by mypy with --strict-equality

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

I'm creating a library of matchers that are used by comparing against values with `==`.  Unfortunately, when comparing a compound type containing a matcher instance against a value with a non-`Any` type, like so:

```py
assert {"foo": SomeMatcher(arg)} == {"foo": 3}
```

then mypy with the `--strict-equality` flag complains about a "Non-overlapping equality check".  For now, I'm working around this by calling the constructors via functions whose return types are annotated as `Any`, but I'm wondering if it's possible to make mypy treat my matcher instances as always `Any` automatically.  I know something like this is possible, as mypy allows `unittest.mock.Mock` instances to be passed in place of non-`Mock` arguments, as though the `Mock` instances all had type `Any` — or is that something hardcoded into mypy?

I've already tried getting this to work by giving my matchers a trivial `__new__` that's annotated with return type `Any`, as well as using a metaclass whose `__new__` had return type `Any`, but neither worked.

An MVCE of a failing matcher:

```py
from typing import Any

class InRange:
    def __init__(self, start: int, end: int) -> None:
        self.start = start
        self.end = end

    def __eq__(self, other: Any) -> bool:
        try:
            return bool(self.start <= other <= self.end)
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            return False


assert {"foo": InRange(1, 5)} == {"foo": 3}
assert {"foo": 3} == {"foo": InRange(1, 5)}
```

Comment: My first thought here would be about why you are using `--strict-equality`. Is it because you want strict equality toggled for other comparisons, but then want to make the matcher comparisons an exception?

Comment: @MarioIshac: Yes, and I also want my library to not raise errors for other users who use `--strict-equality`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mypy does have some hardcoded exceptions for [certain cases, for example `set` and `frozenset`](https://github.com/python/mypy/commit/7678f28f65cf6e878cacd5ba663e6e54347653ae). Although not for `unittest.mock.Mock`, there it's solved [by subclassing `Any`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/f260ea238308fe9ad1b9bd57ed6b573e6b653c97/stdlib/unittest/mock.pyi#L75).

Subclassing `Any` works for type stubs, but at runtime python throws an error: `TypeError: Cannot subclass typing.Any`. The following solves that problem:

```py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, Any

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    Base = Any
else:
    Base = object

class InRange(Base):
    def __init__(self, start: int, end: int) -> None:
        self.start = start
        self.end = end

    def __eq__(self, other: Any) -> bool:
        try:
            return bool(self.start <= other <= self.end)
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            return False


assert {"foo": InRange(1, 5)} == {"foo": 3}
assert {"foo": 3} == {"foo": InRange(1, 5)}
```